# Grails - withRest response is not JSON

Tags: rest, grails

I am using rest plugin 0.8 to perform withRest post request:

```
withRest(id: "spark", uri: "https://my/Url/") {
   def bodyContent = ... 
   def response = post(path: 'myPath', body: bodyContent,
                       headers: [Authorization: "Basic dmhTZHZLY01hYjFFczFEsdfsdfoQzFMOE1IUmd6NUJ6aU86U0p3UcxXVXFLNElhRVhwOQ"],
                       requestContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
}
```

The response should be a JSON by i receive the response parsed and without the required brackets in the keys. 
I tried to add an Accept header but the code did not compile. How can i force the response to be returned as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify that your api is returning response with correct content type header (eg application/json ?) Then rest client should be able to automatically figureout the content type of response and parse it accordingly.

Also try this

```
withRest(id: "spark", uri: "https://my/Url/", contentType:ContentType.JSON) {

}
```